# swimming velocity for whales or fishes

Tags: data-request, biology

Is there some open dataset with maximum swimming velocity and related information about size, for whales or fishes,  which can be used to illustrate Froudes law?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of research papers/study on this subject.

This 1991 paper covers a lot of historical as well as data current at the time.

Fish swimming stride by stride: speed limits and endurance, Videller, 1991
http://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Videler/publication/226033193_Fish_swimming_stride_by_stride_speed_limits_and_endurance/links/0fcfd506672ef8c64f000000.pdf

Here's a 2012 paper on sharks in Greenland

The slowest fish: Swim speed and tail-beat frequency of Greenland sharks, YY Watanabe, 2012
http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Christian_Lydersen/publication/258980090_The_slowest_fish_Swim_speed_and_tail-beat_frequency_of_Greenland_sharks/links/0deec52988c6c8cd91000000.pdf

Here's another paper with data, circa 1990
http://pubs.iclarm.net/Naga/FB_1363.pdf

And here's another paper source:
Morphological predictors of swimming speed: a case study of pre-settlement juvenile coral reef fishes, R Fisher, ‎2007 
http://jeb.biologists.org/content/210/14/2436.long